# Why is GetMetricData returning an empty set of values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Using the JS AWS SDK and passing the following parameters:

```
{
  "StartTime": 1548111915,
  "EndTime": 1549321515,
  "MetricDataQueries": [
    {
      "Id": "m1",
      "MetricStat": {
        "Metric": {
          "MetricName": "NetworkOut",
          "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
          "Dimensions": [
            {
              "Name": "InstanceId",
              "Value": "i-[redacted]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Period": 300,
        "Stat": "Average",
        "Unit": "Gigabytes"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "m1",
    "Label": "NetworkOut",
    "Timestamps": [],
    "Values": [],
    "StatusCode": "Complete",
    "Messages": []
  }
]
```

1. The query closely matches the sample request found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html#API_GetMetricData_Examples
2. I am sure that the instance is a valid instance that has definitely had NetworkOut traffic during that date range.

What reason could account for the lack of elements in `Values` array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution was to omit "Unit" altogether, which allowed AWS to choose the appropriate unit, not only in scale but in category.

Comment: This worked for me in my situation as well. Seems to be the best default course of action.

Answer (score 3):

I tried it and got the same (empty) result as you.

I then changed `Gigabytes` to `Bytes` and got a result. So, it could be that you need to reduce your Unit size.

Here's the command I used for the AWS CLI:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --start-time 1548111915 --end-time 1549321515 --metric-data-queries '[
    {
      "Id": "m1",
      "MetricStat": {
        "Metric": {
          "MetricName": "NetworkOut",
          "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
          "Dimensions": [
            {
              "Name": "InstanceId",
              "Value": "i-xxx"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Period": 300,
        "Stat": "Average",
        "Unit": "Bytes"
      }
    }
  ]'
```

Answer (score 3):

For future inquisitors, there are multiple reasons for which the aws cli silently returns an empty dataset instead of an error, because the input requirements are stricter than the standard user's expectations, but the output requirements are much looser. Examples

- wrong unit
- incomplete list of dimensions
- typos, case-sensitivity, etc

References:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-getmetricstatistics-data/
- https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/9852#issuecomment-395023506

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of other answers, turned out in my case the namespace didn't exist. Ideally an error should be displayed instead of empty data as
I was initially using `AWS/Sagemaker` instead of `AWS/SageMaker`

*Tip: Since there are lot of variables here, using a simple command like `describe` helps narrow things down. I was able to catch this typo using `aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace XYZ` command*

Comment: after changing cloudwatch dimensions name and value , running this cmd in aws-cli 
 "aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace <namespace>" ,
dimension name did change in cmd output