# Empty dataset in Values when using the GetMetricData command from Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Some mates and I are trying to retrieve some data using the `get-metrics-data` command from Cloudwatch. The command is executing properly, but returning an empty set of Values in the response.

We see that there is almost no info about this on the internet, and in SO specifically we've only found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525738/why-is-getmetricdata-returning-an-empty-set-of-values) like this which was resolved because they were missing the "Unit" flag/metric, which is not our case and it probably only applies to some specific cases.

We've read the documentation in AWS about this particular command etc. All required fields are in place and the SQL Expression works inside AWS. The command doesn't complain about anything, it executes successfully but returns an empty array inside Values.

Here I attach **The command** we are executing:

`aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --cli-input-json file://input.json --profile myProfile`

**Our json file's contents**:

```
{
    "StartTime": 1678701600,
    "EndTime": 1678702500,
    "MetricDataQueries": [
        "Id": "myExpression",
        "Expression": "SELECT xxxxxxxxx FROM SCHEMA(\"XXX\", xxx)",
        "Period": 60,
        "ReturnData": true
    ]
}
```

And **the response** we are receiving:

```
{
    “MetricDataResults”: [
        {
            “Id”: “myQuery1”,
            “Label”: “myLabel”,
            “Timestamps”: [],
            “Values”: [],
            “StatusCode”: “Complete”
        }
    ],
    “Messages”: []
}
```

What can be missing or wrong about our command and the input sent to it?